# how to stop RichFaces Skin in jsf 2.0

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm having a problem with skin in jsf. I want to work with my style css instead of skin of RichFaces. I added this code into web.xml :

```
 <context-param>  
     <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>  
     <param-value>false</param-value>  
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
     <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
     <param-value>plain</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

but i still have problem with `input[type=submit]`. How can i stop RichFaces Skin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem is with your css? Simple define myButton style in css and use it in `<h:commandButton styleClass="myButton" />`.

Comment: @Vasil Lukach i did it the same way but it doesn't work for me in the input[type=submit] because RichFaces has already a default background specified on the input[type=submit] CSS selector which is a stronger my css selector

Comment: You need load your css in proper place (after RichFaces css). Add following link in `<h:body>` of your template: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/myCustom.css" media="all" />` and check result (where myCustom is name of your css file and put proper path).

Comment: Is there something else related to skinning in your web.xml? `org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning=false` should get rid of the `skinning.ecss`.

Comment: it works by added !important to css file..@Vasil Lukach i will try your solution..@Makhiel i don't know what you meant ? thanks for your reply

Comment: `skinning.ecss` contains the styles for control elements, it shouldn't be present inside `<head>` if you turn the control skinning off